# How can I display a tree from fetched json objects in react?

Tags: reactjs, json, axios, tree

I try to display a JSON tree object after I fetched it with axios in React.

Backend_URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/nodes
Frontend_URL: http://localhost:3000/nodes

Response in Browser for Backend_URL:
{"europe": "25", "france": "25.26", "germany": "25.27", "marseille": "25.26.28", "paris": "25.26.29", "dusseldorf": "25.27.30", "koln": "25.27.31", "berlin": "25.27.32"}

Response in Browser for Frontend_URL:
25
25.26
25.27

The numbers are for: continent.country.town

**Nodes.jsx:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


 function Nodes({ data }) {
    
    const [node, setNodes] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:5000/nodes')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                setNodes(res.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>       
            <ul>
                <li>
                    {node.europe}
                </li>
                <li>
                    {node.France}
                </li>
                <li>
                    {node.germany}
                </li>  
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Nodes
```

But I want a Frontend Page like:

- Europe

  - Germany

    - Berlin
    - Köln
    - Düsseldorf
  - France

    - Paris
    - Marseille

How can I display the Json in my Nodes.jsx correctly?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Something like this:                                                                                                         ```return (
        <div>       
           <ul>
                {data && data.map(item => (
                <li>
                    {item.title}
                    {item.childNodes && <Tree data={item.childNodes} />}
                </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );```